# Fill dynamic <div>'s with content. But how to show it?

Tags: html, css, dynamic

My intention is to have 4 main Nav-bars at a site. If the user hovers one, it expands and should show content. But how should I do the content part?

```
#bottom-menu:hover #contact{
    visibility: visible ;
}
```

If I make it visible when the box is fully expanded, it works but there is an issue: The content, while not visible, is still there and needs room which causes the layout to collapse.

I would like to do that with pure CSS, allthough i'm aware of jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/RbZwx/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`visibility: hidden` causes the element to continue to [consume layout space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/visibility).

`display:none` causes it to take up [no layout space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display).

Think "spoilers" vs "hidden".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/visibility

> The visibility CSS property is used for two things:
>
> - The hidden value hides an element but leaves space where it would have been.
> - The collapse value hides rows or columns of a table. It also collapses XUL elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display

> The display CSS property specifies the type of rendering box used for an element. In HTML, default display property values are taken from behaviors described in the HTML specifications or from the browser/user default stylesheet. The default value in XML is inline.
>
> In addition to the many different display box types, the value none lets you turn off the display of an element; when you use none, all child elements also have their display turned off. The document is rendered as though the element doesn't exist in the document tree.

I would still encourage you to read both of these, and to learn how they affect the page more than just for this particular case.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: none`. See [CSS 2.1: 11.2 Visibility: the 'visibility' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#visibility):

> The `'visibility'` property specifies whether the boxes generated by an element are rendered. Invisible boxes still affect layout (set the `'display'` property to `'none'` to suppress box generation altogether). Values have the following meanings: [...]
>
> **`hidden`** The generated box is invisible (fully transparent, nothing is drawn), but still affects layout. Furthermore, descendants of the element will be visible if they have `'visibility: visible'`.

Comment: Ah! W3, you beat me to referencing it, I was going for the more accessible but less complete MDN ...